# Get son reference in father template

Tags: symfony, twig

I am working with symfony and twig and i'm trying to do something like that

I have a first twig template named `father.html.twig`
in this father i have a div and a button

```
<div class="container">
</div>
<button class="button>I AM A BUTTON</button>
```

and in my script i have something like that :

```
 <script>
    $.('button').on('click,function(){
        $ajax({
            url : 'url'
            type: 'POST'
            data: 'data'
        }).done(function(data){
             $('.container').html(data).show();
        })
     })
<script>
```

So far so good. So my controller render an other twig :

```
return $this->render('son.html.twig', array(
                "data1" => "data1",
                "data2"=>'I eat apple'
       ));
```

So a lot of unrevelant things happen in son.html.twig but I want to know, how can i access to `data2`in my father.html.twig and do something like that

```
 <div class="container">
       here we have son.html.twig
 </div>
 <button class="button>I AM A BUTTON</button>
 <p> {{ data2 }} </p>
```

and have "I eat apple" displayed. And everytime i'm clicking on `I am a button` the data2 is gonna be different ofc

Answer (score 0):

you can render another controller in any place of your father template:

```
<div class="container">
      {{ render(controller('AcmeBundle:Default:son')) }}
</div>
<button class="button>I AM A BUTTON</button>
<p> {{ data2 }} </p>
```

where `AcmeBundle:Default:son` is shortcut for AcmeBundle\DefaultController::sonAction()

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/embedding_controllers.html

P.S.

of course you must have separate action that renders your father template like this:

```
fatherAction()
{
    return $this->render('father.html.twig', array());
}
```